# R/Plotly: Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list

Tags: r, function, plot, plotly

I'm moderately experienced using R, but I'm just starting to learn to write functions to automate tasks. I'm currently working on a project to run sentiment analysis and topic models of speeches from the five remaining presidential candidates and have run into a snag.

I wrote a `function` to do a sentence-by-sentence analysis of positive and negative sentiments, giving each sentence a score. Miraculously, it worked and gave me a dataframe with scores for each sentence.

```
    score        text
1     1        iowa, thank you.
2     2        thanks to all of you here tonight for your patriotism, for your love of country and for doing what too few americans today are doing.  
3     0        you are not standing on the sidelines complaining. 
4     1        you are not turning your backs on the political process.
5     2        you are standing up and fighting back.
```

So what I'm trying to do now is create a `function` that takes the scores and figures out what percentage of the total is represented by the count of each score and then plot it using `plotly`. So here is the function I've written:

```
scoreFun <- function(x){{
  tbl <- table(x)
  res <- cbind(tbl,round(prop.table(tbl)*100,2))
  colnames(res) <- c('Score', 'Count','Percentage')
  return(res)
}
  percent = data.frame(Score=rownames, Count=Count, Percentage=Percentage)
  return(percent)
}
```

Which returns this:

```
saPct <- scoreFun(sanders.scores$score)
saPct

     Count Percentage
-6     1       0.44
-5     1       0.44
-4     6       2.64
-3    13       5.73
-2    20       8.81
-1    42      18.50
0     72      31.72
1     34      14.98
2     18       7.93
3      9       3.96
4      6       2.64
5      2       0.88
6      1       0.44
9      1       0.44
11     1       0.44
```

What I had hoped it would return is a dataframe with what has ended up being the `rownames` as a variable called `Score` and the next two columns called `Count` and `Percentage`, respectively. Then I want to plot the `Score` on the x-axis and `Percentage` on the y-axis using this code:

```
d <- subplot(
  plot_ly(clPct, x = rownames, y=Percentage, xaxis="x1", yaxis="y1"),
  plot_ly(saPct, x = rownames, y=Percentage, xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2"),
  margin = 0.05,
  nrows=2
) %>% layout(d, xaxis=list(title="", range=c(-15, 15)),
             xaxis2=list(title="Score", range=c(-15,15)),
             yaxis=list(title="Clinton", range=c(0,50)),
             yaxis2=list(title="Sanders", range=c(0,50)),showlegend = FALSE)
d
```

I'm pretty certain I've made some obvious mistakes in my `function` and my `plot_ly` code, because clearly it's not returning the dataframe I want and is leading to the error `Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list` when I run the `plotly code. Again, though, I'm not very experienced writing functions and I've not found a similar issue when I Google, so I don't know how to fix this.

Any advice would be most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: what does str(saPct) return?

Comment: `num [1:15, 1:2] 1 1 6 13 20 42 72 34 18 9 ...  
     - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      ..$ : chr [1:15] "-6" "-5" "-4" "-3" ...  
..$ : chr [1:2] "Count" "Percentage"`

Comment: so it's list, you need to turn it into a data frame (clPct as well)

Comment: Thanks! I turned it into a data frame, but I lost the row names, which are the `scores` that I want for my plot. Then, I tried to backtrack and rerun the `scoreFun` function and it's not working now. It's giving me this error: `'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]`. My `prop.table` isn't returning the row names as part of the vector. I got partial code from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623763/in-r-how-can-i-compute-percentage-statistics-on-a-column-in-a-dataframe-tabl). There are other code examples there, so I will try them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@MLavoie, this code from the question I referenced in my comment did the trick. Many thanks!

```
scoreFun <- function(x){
  tbl <- data.frame(table(x))
  colnames(tbl) <- c("Score", "Count")
  tbl$Percentage <- tbl$Count / sum(tbl$Count) * 100
  return(tbl)
}
```