# Count distinct among the rows and aggregate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set as shown below:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~top_1, ~top_2, ~top_3,
  "A",     "B",    "C",
  "B",     "B",    "B",   
  "C",     "B",    "C",
  "A",     "B",    "B",
  "A",     "A",    "A",
  "B",     "B",    "A",
  "C",     "A",    "C",
  "A",     "A",    "A",
  "A",     "C",    "B",
  "B",     "B",    "C",
)
```

And now, I want to count distinct the rows for each column and have a new data set something like this:

```
new_data <- tribble(
  ~product, ~top_1, ~top_2, ~top_3,
     "A",    .50,    .30,     .30,
     "B",    .30,    .60,     .30,
     "C",    .20,    .10,     .40,
)
```

Could you please help me to be able to create this data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column-Wise Percentage of Different Entires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623763/in-r-how-can-i-compute-percentage-statistics-on-a-column-in-a-dataframe-tabl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where we `gather` into 'long' format, get the `count` and reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
   gather %>% 
   group_by_all %>% 
   count %>%
   group_by(key) %>%
   mutate(n = n/sum(n)) %>% 
   pivot_wider( names_from = key, values_from = n)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   value [3]
#  value top_1 top_2 top_3
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       0.5   0.3   0.3
#2 B       0.3   0.6   0.3
#3 C       0.2   0.1   0.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Well, if I have more than 10 rows, should I replace 10 with the number of rows?

Comment: Somehow, it did not come out as a percentage. The sum of each column should be 100%.

Comment: @zineda Sorry, that was a bug.  I fixed it

Answer (score 4):

```
lvl = unique(unlist(data))
sapply(data, function(x) prop.table(table(factor(x, lvl))))
#  top_1 top_2 top_3
#A   0.5   0.3   0.3
#B   0.3   0.6   0.3
#C   0.2   0.1   0.4
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there anyway to have it as a data frame?

Comment: @zineda, just wrap it in `as.data.frame()` - `as.data.frame(sapply(data, function(x) prop.table(table(factor(x, lvl)))))`

Answer (score 3):

One `base R` option could be:

```
table(stack(data))/nrow(data)

values top_1 top_2 top_3
     A   0.5   0.3   0.3
     B   0.3   0.6   0.3
     C   0.2   0.1   0.4
```

And if you want it as a `data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(data))/nrow(data))
```